# What is the use of npm, grunt etc. in front-end development?

Tags: html, frontend

I want to know what is exact use of npm, grunt etc. in front-end development?
Why and how to use it?

Comment: http://gruntjs.com/, https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/what-is-npm, ...
etc. I do not know... please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

NPM is a Node Package Manager - you can think of it as a way to automate a lot of installations for you by a single command using the CL (command line). Otherwise you would have to install all the scripts manually, which is generally rather messy, since they are often not as user-friendly as say... game or standard program installations.

Grunt/Gulp/Broccoli/etc. - While I am not using it myself, from what I heard and read: It is a tool, that can help you automate numerous tasks, you would have to normally do manually. Anything ranging from compiling any CSS/HTML/JS preprocessor, concatenating different files together into one big file, watching for changes in files to automatically upload them to a server and so on. Basically it is a highly configurable tool meant to help you automate mundane and boring tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, NPM is a package manager what allows you to download a lot of packages of software such as Gulp and Grunt, but also Bootstrap etc with the command line. You have to install node.js for this. You don't need this as a front-end developer but it will make installing the software much easier than install it manually which take mostly more time.

- https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/what-is-npm for npm
- https://www.npmjs.com/browse/star for popular modules

Software such as Grunt and Gulp will help front-end developers mostly with compiling SASS and LESS, CSS preprocessors which saves you time and allows you to have more functions in your css. Grunt, Gulp etc runs in the command line and makes it easier to edit your files. For example, I use myself Gulp in combination with SASS. Because SASS has to compile to css I have set up a command which automatically compiles my SASS files to a CSS file if I hit the save button in my code editor, the SASS:Watch plugin.

I highly recommend using SASS, and so using Gulp or Grunt.

- http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html SASS documentation
- http://gulpjs.com/ Gulp documentation
- http://gulpjs.com/plugins/ plug ins for gulp